# How/Where do I drag an mp3 file from my pc to iphone?

Tags: iphone, mp3

The only folder I see in internal storage for Apple iPhone is DCIM which leads to 100APPLE, which has all my pictures and videos, and I can't drag the mp3 file there? [image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need [iTunes](https://www.apple.com/itunes/) to copy music from your computer to your iPhone.